# submit form to check something with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a form to check a security code. In fact, I am new to ajax and jquery, so I tried what I can, but my code doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

#### php file :

```
<?php 
include('/includes/db-connect.php');

if( isset($_POST["seccode"]) ){
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `certificate_acheived_tbl` WHERE `cert_check_code` = ".$seccode.")";
    if( mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {    
        echo "<script>alert('s')";
    }
}
?>
```

#### js file:

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn btn-success").click(function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cert-check-ajax.php",
            data: 'certcode='+ ID,
            success: function() {
                $('#someHiddenDiv').show();
                console.log();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is simply not a substantive enough problem statement for anyone to do anything but guess. Time to read up on basic troubleshooting and debugging or provide a lot more detail

Comment: where you define `$seccode`?

Comment: it is in the form

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Answer (score 0):

your code is bad... (sometimes mine too)

One first mistake  :  `data: 'certcode='+ ID`,  in jQuery

and `isset($_POST["seccode"])` in PHP   `'certcode' != 'seccode'`

so a better code.. ?

jQuery  (I allways use JSON, it's more easy)

```
$(function () {
    $(".btn btn-success").click(function() {
        var 
        Call_Args = {
            certcode:  $(this).attr('id')
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cert-check-ajax.php',  
            type: 'POST',
            data: Call_Args,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log( data.acceptCod );    // or data['acceptCod'] if you want
                $('#someHiddenDiv').show();
                // ...
            } 
        }); //$.ajax
    });  // btn btn-success").click
});
```

PHP (with utf8 insurance, and good header / JSON encode response )

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
include('/includes/db-connect.php');

$T_Repons['acceptCod'] = "bad";

if (isSet($_POST['certcode'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `certificate_acheived_tbl` ";
    $sql .= "WHERE `cert_check_code` = ".$_POST['certcode'].")";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $T_Repons['acceptCod'] = (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) ? "ok" : "bad";
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($T_Repons);
exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: $T_Repons['acceptCod'] = ( mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) ? "ok", "bad";
 saying  ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: Did you notice my new correction and testing it ?
no answer or anything; is it something wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use it

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn btn-success").click(function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cert-check-ajax.php",
            data: {'seccode': ID}
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#someHiddenDiv').show();
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: if you compare my script with your script, you can see

Comment: First of all I am not the OP. Second there is nothing inherently wrong with the way their ajax is configured. String vs object for data is minor variation...both are correct. Same with `done()` vs `success`. You haven't explained why your solution would help